# Cambiar el Navbar dinámicamente cuando esta en $_SESSION logueado el usuario

Tags: php, html

Básicamente este es mi navbar y quisiera que cuando el usuario este logueado cambie el navbar para que aparezca log out, perfil, etc.

**¿Cómo haría ese código?**

Gracias.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img utiles/socialprop5.png" width="60px"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-collapse collapse">
            <li><a href="faq/faq.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> F.A.Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="modaltrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></span> Accede</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="modaltrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></span> Registrate</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el nav utilizaría algo así:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                      </button>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img utiles/socialprop5.png" width="60px"></a>
        </div>
        <?php
            //En el if va la variable con la que identificas si estan logueados
            if($_SESSION['login'] == true){
        ?>
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-collapse collapse">
            <li><a href="faq/faq.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> F.A.Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="modaltrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_perfil"> Perfil</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="modaltrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_logout"> Cerrar sessión</a></li>

        </div>
            
        <?php
            //Acción que se ejecutaria en caso de que no estes logueado
            }else{
        ?>
        //Aquí iría el menu que quieres mostrar en caso de que no estes logueado
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-collapse collapse">
            <li><a href="faq/faq.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> F.A.Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="modaltrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></span> Accede</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="modaltrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" ></span> Registrate</a></li>

        </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sisi al final pude hacerlo, mi pregunta para hacer un session destroy, podria poner esta funcion en el boton logout?

Comment: si lo pueddes hacer claro que tendria que ir en el botón del menú cuando esta el usuario en sesión `<li><a href="logout.php" id="modaltrigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_logout"> Cerrar sessión</a></li>` en logout.php estaria el código de session destroy

Comment: Dale! muchas gracias por los tips!! abrazo