# Habilitar href dependiendo del usuario con sesion iniciada para ciertos permisos

Tags: php, html, jquery

Necesito habilitar un href a cierto rol de usuario usando sesiones. Por ejemplo si X usuario tiene la sesion activa.

Ejemplo:

`if($_SESSION['usuario']=="X")` habilitar que pueda abrir una liga por ejemplo `<a href="#gerencias.php">Gerencias Administrativas</a>`

`if($_SESSION['usuario']=="Y")` habilitar que pueda abrir una liga por ejemplo `<a href="#Sistemas.php">Gerencias Administrativas</a>`

`if($_SESSION['usuario']=="A")` habilitar que pueda abrir una liga por ejemplo `<a href="#usuarios.php">Gerencias Administrativas</a>`

Es decir que X e Y tenga permisos tambien para el A
el A no debe tener acceso a X ni a Y

¿Con que me recomiendan usando jquery o como podria hacerle. Gracias.

Ejemplos

Hace Login
[image: Login]
el usuario logueado lalcolea le permita ingresar al apartado Gerencia Administrativa y Usuarios por ejemplo, pero no al de Recursos Humanos ni Sistemas
[image: Menu]
Y visualiza la Informacion de Gerencia Administrativa
[image: Datos]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que dependiendo del usuario se mostrará un link u otro?

Comment: Ejemplo Existe un Menu

Comment: Usuarios  °   Recursos Humanos  ° Gerencias  ° Sistemas

Comment: Si yo "Recursos Humanos" le doy click al menu Recursos Humanos me permita ingresar al portal de Recursos Humanos. Si no soy de RH que no me permita ingresar a la liga.

Comment: Más importante que no mostrar los enlaces es asegurarse de que esos roles no tendrán acceso a esas páginas. Si la única manera en la que se comprueba es mostrando/ocultado enlaces, entonces hay un problema grave de seguridad.

Comment: De hecho lo que hice fue crear roles en una tabla independiente para que de acuerdo a username lo compruebe y de acuerdo al rol le habilite la liga. ¿alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de hacer un menú para ciertos roles, debes asegurarte que en las páginas también se valide el rol puesto que se puede acceder a la página directo por url.

Entonces, conozco dos modos de hacer esto:

1. Código puramente
2. Por medio de tablas donde defines los roles

De las dos es mucho mejor la segunda por cuestiones de mantenimiento. Imagina que de repente necesitas modificar o agregar un rol, sería lidioso entrar al código. Es mejor hacer los cambios en una tabla o **crear un panel donde un administrador pueda asignar dichos roles.**

Obviamente este post no es cabida para esta opción por su naturaleza. Así que te pondré cómo validar las sesiones para crear un menú y para dar acceso a una página. Ya es decisión tuya si optas por hacerlo así o con la opción 2 (tendrías que investigar o crear una pregunta nueva).

**Para mostrar links de menu:**

```
function get_menu( $usuario)
{

  $menu = array();

  // O haces un swith

  if ( $usuario === 'A' )
  {
    $menu = array( 'link1' => 'opcion1', 'link2' => 'opcion2', 'linkN' => 'opcionN');
  }

  if ( $usuario === 'B' )
  {
     $menu = array( 'link1' => 'opcion1', 'link2' => 'opcion2', 'linkN' => 'opcionN');
  }

  if ( $usuario === 'C' )
  {
     $menu = array( 'link1' => 'opcion1', 'link2' => 'opcion2', 'linkN' => 'opcionN');
  }

  return $menu; 

  }
```

Y lo imprimes así:

```
session_start();

$menu = get_menu($_SESSION['usuario']);

// O haces una funcion para imprimir 
foreach( $menu as $link => $opcion){

  // ya lo imprimes con tu formato para estilos, aquí es sólo una demostración
  echo "<a href=\"$link.php\">$opcion </a>";

}
```

Hasta aquí todo bonito, ahora simplemente hay que validar en cada página del siguiente modo siempre al inicio de cada archivo:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
  // Terminamos o redirigimos con header location
  die('Acceso denegado');

}

$menu = get_menu($_SESSION['usuario']);

// Flag para el acceso
$acceso = false;

foreach ( $menu as $link => $opcion){
  if ( $link === $_SERVER[PHP_SELF])
  {
    $acceso = true;
  }
}

if (! $acceso)
  die('Acceso denegado');
```

Y con esto debe bastar. Lo importante es **entender la lógica.** Como ves, la naturaleza de hacerlo con puro código es la de acomplejar el sistema y eso a la larga es suicidio.

Espero te sirva!

**Nota:**

También falta añadir que $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] te dará la ruta exacta del archivo, con todo y su ruta si es que no está en raíz. Entonces tendrías que hacer esto dentro del foreach:

```
$array_opcion = explode('/', $link);
$pagina = array_pop($array_opcion);
if ( $link === $pagina)
```

Comment: De hecho podrías crear una función para validar el acceso al archivo (la última parte del código) e invocarla tantas veces necesites.

Comment: También falta añadir que $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] te dará la ruta exacta del archivo, con todo y su ruta si es que no está en raíz.

Entonces tendrías que hacer esto dentro del foreach: 

$array_opcion = explode('/', $opcion);

$pagina = array_pop($opcion);

De este modo obtienes un array con la ruta separada por índices según su /. Luego extraes la última que es la página como tal.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear menús dependiendo del usuario logueado aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```html
<?php
            //En el if va la variable con la que identificas al usuario
            if($_SESSION['user'] == "A"){
        ?>
    
    Escribes el menu o <href> que necesitas mostrar al usuario de ese tipo 

<?php } else if($_SESSION['user'] == "B") { ?>

Escribes el menu o <href> que necesitas mostrar al usuario de ese tipo  


<?php } ?>
```

Y asi dependiendo del usuario logueado te va a mostrar menus con links hacia diferentes partes de tu aplicación.

Te dejo un ejemplo [Menu dependiendo si esta logueado o no](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/27893/cambiar-el-navbar-din%C3%A1micamente-cuando-esta-en-session-logueado-el-usuario/27905#27905)

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos por sus aportes. Lo que hice fue crear una tabla con los username y les asigne un rol. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posterior al momento de hacer login el usuario si coincide con el lalcolea le mostrara el menu Gerencia Administrativa [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir en la barra de menus solo le mostrara Gerencia Administrativa y no Recursos Humanos como tampoco Sistemas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto debido a que en php coloque CASE para que dependiendo del username le muestre el Href para validar y darle acceso a la siguiente pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posterior lo redirecciona a validar.php para buscar el username en la tabla alterna que les mostre en la primera imagen llamada usuarios_mb y verifica el rol o cuenta [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta parte si existe el username y el rol es 1 entonces le da el paso al index_ga

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen hago validacion tanto con un case como con una validacion a una bd